# ASP.NET Identity and validation of a custom claim

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I am using ASP.NET Identity with MVC, and I set a sessionId (GuId string) on each logged in user for each one of his devices. The idea is that a user can remove device sessions, and then that device will not be logged in anymore (as it is done in dropbox, and google).

Currently, I set this sessionId as a claim in ASP.NET Identity, so it is passed in the authentication cookie.

For Authenrication I use ASP.NET Identity as the samples: app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions{....

My questions:

1. Is setting my sessionId to the claims the right approach here?
2. Also, where in the whole authentication process can I validate the claim of that sessionId?
3. My current idea is to validate this sessionId against a database table for each request. Should I use Request.Sessions to store the sessionId instead, or any other idea here?

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure or this will help you. but when creating your MVC project you got the option to set an Authentication method. that should generate example code. Which I asume should be an acceptable approach for the situation of keeping tracks of your users.

Comment: Through ASP.NET Identity I use app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions{....
How should I use this option to validate my sessionIds?

Comment: Something I should have mentioned in my earlier answer: if you want to sign the user everywhere for everything, all you have to do is change the value of the security stamp in the AspNetUser table. `SecurityStampValidator` checks the auth cookie against this value, and signs them out if it's changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a user can have multiple valid sessions, you would either need to store these as claims or create your own table to store them. Since claims is already created by Identity, that will be easiest.

You'd validate this in the `OnValidateIdentity` method of `CookieAuthenticationProvider` in `Startup.Auth.cs`. Currently this calls the `OnValidateIdentity` method of the `SecurityStampValidator` so you need to write a wrapper method that first checks your session id and then calls the original security stamp validator. For example you could add these methods to the `Startup` class:

```
private Func<CookieValidateIdentityContext, System.Threading.Tasks.Task> _validate=SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
           validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
           regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager));
private async Task validate(CookieValidateIdentityContext context)
{
    var usermanager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var claims = await usermanager.GetClaimsAsync(context.Identity.GetUserId());

    //instead of setting to true, add your session validation logic here
    bool sessionIsValid=true;

    if (!sessionIsValid) {
        context.RejectIdentity();
        context.OwinContext.Authentication.SignOut(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
    }

    await _validate(context);
}
```

where `_validate` is just the original method and `validate` is your new method that also checks session id. Then your `app.UseCookieAuthentication` code will reference the new `validate` method like this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
        OnValidateIdentity = validate

    }
});
```

To make this work I think you'll need to check the claims from the database every time, but I believe the `usermanager.GetClaimsAsync` will ultimately do this.